# I wrote a script that's supposed to make a directory. It works without sudo, but doesn't with it. THe script is required to be called with sudo

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I'm supposed to make a script that backups some files from `/etc` into a directory
that I must create called `backup-confs`. The problem is that I must run the script with sudo, but when I do it doesn't create the directory. It works fine without, but I can't figure out why it doesn't work with sudo.

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir /home/student/tema3-scripts-output/backup-confs 2>> err.txt
```

This version also doesn't work

```
#!/bin/bash
cd 2>> err.txt..
cd tema3-scripts-output 2>> err.txt
mkdir backup-confs 2>> err.txt
cd .. 2>> err.txt
cd tema3-scripts 2>> err.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont do it all in one, split it up.
Maybe is has problems with creating a directory and at the same time redirecting the output from "*.../backup-confs*"

1. try using absolute references `sudo mkdir /home/some-new-dir`
2. give permissions to file `chmod 777 /home/some-new-dir`

and a personal preference, use "copy": `cp /home/student/some-config /home/some-new-dir/some-config`

Answer (score 0):

I see you are working with relative directory references (like `cd tema...` instead of `cd /tmp/tema...`). When running under `sudo`, you are changing user, which might mean that you are changing directory, therefore I would advise you always to work with absolute directory references.